# Redefining sectioning commands

Tags: macros, sections-paragraphs

I'm trying to redefine the `\subsubsection` of the report class to behave like `\paragraph` and not have a linebreak after the title.

It's closely related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5035/paragraph-style-how-to-force-line-break-paragraph-make-paragraph-a-hea) but I have no idea how to extrapolate the reverse effect from it.

I tried to get the code for paragraph using `\show\paragraph` and redifining `\subsubsection` with it as follows, but although it does compile, it doesn't work when I try to use it.

```
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\long macro :->\@startsection{subsubsection}{4}{\z@ }{3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries}}
```

I'm would like to know how to solve my original problem, but now, I'm also curious as to what I did wrong with that `\renewcommand` since it seems to me like I'd encounter it again with other problems I'd try to solve by modifying how latex does its thing.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{listings}

\def\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\def\thesubsection{\thesection.\Alph{subsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

%\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\long macro :->\@startsection{subsubsection}{4}{\z@ }{3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalfont \normalsize \bfseries}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{c:c1}

\section{Section 1}
\label{s:s1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
\label{ss:ss1}

\subsubsection{\lstinline{<Upper|Lower> Triangular}} defines a triangular matrix ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `titlesec` package to (re-)define macros like that. See [Defining custom sectioning commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17275/defining-custom-sectioning-commands).

Comment: Also the `\long macro :->` is part of the `\show` output and not part of the definition, i.e. you should delete it.

Comment: @Martin: Sorry, I saw your second comment only after I posted my answer.

Comment: @Michael: No problem.

Comment: @Martin: I saw the titlesec package in the question I linked, and I guess I could (should?) have looked deeper into that packages.  But at this point, my curiosity on how to redefine the code won over practicality :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The output of `\show` cannot be used as you are trying. It says that `\subsection` is a "long" macro that has no arguments and the replacement text is what follows `->`.

The right place where to look is `report.cls`, where you find

```
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

The key point that explain the different behavior are: the negative fourth argument of `\@startsection` for `\subsubsection` which suppresses indentation of the following paragraph; the positive fifth argument tells TeX that the title will not be "run-in". So

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

The second argument to `\@startsection` tells LaTeX the level of the sectioning command for the purposes of `secnumdepth` and `tocdepth` and should stay `3`.

### Important note

The `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` commands are necessary because we are doing stuff involving the internal command of LaTeX.

Every time a command containing `@` in its name has to be used, the code must either be in a `.sty` file or surrounded by that pair. See [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) for more information.

Comment: To see the definition you can also use [`texdef`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) `-t latex -c report subsubsection paragraph` (or `latexdef` instead `texdef -t latex` if that symlink is installed). However, looking into the source file directly has the benefit that you see the code as it was formatted by the author.

Comment: @Martin: but it uses the same output as `\show`. I think that the main part of my answer is to explain what went wrong to begin with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the details, I'm now a little less ignorant in the ways of latex :)

Comment: @egreg: Indeed (I actually added that to my comment while you were responding ;-) ). I just wanted to point the possibility out, nothing against the answer.

Answer (score 3):

`\long macro :->` is not part of the definition of the macro, and you need to change the catcode of `@` in the definition. The following should work:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefered not to do things manually, you can use [the `titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) whose usage is described in this question: [Defining custom sectioning commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17275/defining-custom-sectioning-commands)