# How do I change the way section headings look?

Tags: sectioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)
>   [Redefining sectioning commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22576/redefining-sectioning-commands)
>   [\@ title and You can’t use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54097/title-and-you-cant-use-spacefactor-in-vertical-mode)

I have a few sections in my document that look like

```
\section*{Introduction}
```

The font size seems slightly too big for me, and I would like to make it smaller. I found the following `\renewcommand` snippet ([link here](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/thesis/node9.html)):

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
{section}%                      %the name
{1}%                            %the level
{0mm}%                          %the indent
{-\baselineskip}%               %the before skip
{0.5\baselineskip}%             %the after skip
{\normalfont\large\itshape}}%   %the style
```

But I get the error

> You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode

How would I go about solving this problem?

Thank you,

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do

Comment: @egreg I don't understand how your link relates to my question here. Could you be more specific?

Comment: The command `\@startsection` you're using has `@` in its name; that thread addresses precisely this problem: put `\makeatletter` before and `\makeatother` after that code.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I'll accept your answer if you write it up below as an actual answer.

Comment: Don't be afraid to make other questions; this wasn't easy to find and we're discussing about how making the problem and its solution more visible on the site.