# New line after paragraph?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [paragraph style - how to force line break? \paragraph{} \\ - make paragraph a header?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5035/paragraph-style-how-to-force-line-break-paragraph-make-paragraph-a-he)

I have the following problem. I have a paragraph and only after this single paragraph environemnt I want to have the text following in a new line. So the original source looks
like this here:

```
\paragraph{Some title stuff.}

bla bla bla
```

I tried to add `\linebreak`

```
\paragraph{Some title stuff.} \linebreak

bla bla bla
```

and also `\\`, but nothing worked, in each case I got the error message "There is no line here to end".

Anyone an idea how to sort this problem?

Comment: Do `\subsubsection` or [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) do what you want?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @TEX.SE admins -->IMO this is not an exact duplicate because the linked to question solves the problem for non-standard requirements... where as this question assumes a standard document without any weird TOC requirements. Also this question has a simpler solution and is more elegant GIVEN regular TOC requirements.

Answer (score 144):

You can always cheat the "there is no line here to end" error with empty `\mbox{}`es. For example:

```
\paragraph{Some title stuff.}\mbox{}\\
bla bla bla
```

For convenience you can define your own paragraph before `\begin{document}`

```
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
```

and just use your new command:

```
\myparagraph{Some title stuff.}
bla bla bla
```

Comment: this gives me an underfull \hbox, how can I discard the warning?

Comment: with ~\\ you obtain the same effect

Answer (score 20):

You need something just after your paragraph definition before you can break the line. That something in my case is an empty `\mbox{}`. This is a very elementary way of doing things. It may be automated using [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), as @Andrey suggests.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Some title stuff.}\mbox{} \\

bla bla bla
\end{document}
```