# How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I have a document which requires many levels of sectioning. I have sections, subsections and subsubsections, but require one more level below that. I can't change the sections to be parts and move everything up a level, as this document will eventually be included in another document which has parts/chapters already.

I see that the `\paragraph` command is used for defining the section level below subsubsection, but that doesn't produce headings in the same way that subsection and subsubsection do. Is there any way to either (1) change the `\paragraph` command so that it works like subsubsection but just adds another number - ie. 1.2.3.4 or (2) create a `\subsubsubsection` command to do the same thing?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30997/more-section-headings

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the first answer below (see comment on that answer) - it doesn't quite work. Does anyone have any ideas? I really need to sort the numbering for my report out soon before it goes to my supervisor!

Comment: What kind of document requires this many levels of headings?

Comment: @mrf One example: Documents a person writes for themselves to keep track of what they've learned. My thesis (master's) adviser teaches so much so much so fast - or I'm that slow - that I forget it quickly. The best way for me to retain what he taught is to type it up - which is how he advised me to work with him when we started. To quickly locate parts of the document, my subsubsections have subsections and subsubsections. Then I use package hyperref to create an index so I can find them quickly. But note that I type really fast (and can learn LaTeX somewhat fast).

Comment: This seems like something quite a few people are into; is there any plan to develop a command which copies the style of a section level to a different level.

`\newsectionstyle[\subsubsection][4]{\subsubsubsection}` 
`\renewsectionstyle[\subsubsection]{\paragraph}`

or something along those lines. I understand that more powerful commands exist, but this specific feature seems to have gotten a large number of views and may be something to which a very basic user would like easy access.

Comment: Does a simple KOMA-Script answer exist for this? The answer seems like it would be in Section 3.16 of the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) but I can't make heads or tails if there is an answer.

Comment: @kando I've added a KOMA-Script answer.

Comment: @kando And there is already [another questions for KOMA-Script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/356567/9057).

Answer (score 352, accepted):

You can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to change the way `\paragraph` formats the titles and set the `secnumdepth` counter to four to obtain numbering for the paragraphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
test
\subsection{Test Subsection}
test
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
test
\paragraph{Test Modified Paragraph}
test

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to define a new sectioning command, you can take a look at [Defining custom sectioning commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17275/3954).

If you want to define a fresh new sectional unit below `\subsubsection`, but above `\paragraph`, then you will have to do considerably more work: a new counter has to be created and its representation has to be appropriately defined; the sectional units `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` will also have to be redefined, as well as they corresponding `\l@...` commands (controlling how the will be typeset in the ToC if the `tocdepth` value is increased); also, the toclevel (for eventual bookmarks) will have to be considered.

Here's an example showing how to obtain this new sectional unit giving you now the option to use `\part`, `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\subsubsubsection`, `\paragraph`, and `\subparagraph`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test Section}
test
\subsection{Test Subsection}
test
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
test
\subsubsubsection{Test Subsubsubsection}
test
\paragraph{Test Paragraph}
test
\subparagraph{Test Subparagraph}
test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I've been using it and have only just realised that the section numbering for `\subsubsubsection` doesn't seem to restart after every `\subsubsection`. That is, I get 1.1.1, 1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2, 1.1.2, 1.1.2.3 - where the last one should be 1.1.2.1. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @robintw You have to say `\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]` so that the new counter is bound to the `subsubsection` counter.

Comment: I applied the first solution (with `\paragraph`) - it works great, only in the ToC, it looks like [this](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/paragraph.png) - do you know how to make the alignment match?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Did you notice [\subsubsubsection count not reset when starting a new section, subsection, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161442)? Seems also to have been thematized in comments above mine here.

Comment: @Speravir thanks for the reminder. I've fixed it now.

Comment: I like the solution a lot! This should be a package with options, such as `[compact]` of the `titlesec` package (since it is a required package). How do I reference the new subsubsubsection? I use the `cleveref` package and it can't determine the label type ("section"), so it produces two ?? instead of "section 1.1.1.1".

Comment: Concerning the 'fresh new' `\subsubsubsection`, I think you forgot `#1` in the last argument of `\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}{...}{...}{1em}{}`.

Comment: @barto No, since i am not using the `explicit` option for `titlesec`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina thanks a lot , my issue is that the subsubsection and subsubsubsection are aligned with the same margin , i'm using report as document class .... this worked fine when using article but  i want it with report ... please view the image that describe my problem here : http://s3.postimg.org/wzzluctj7/margin_Section.png can you help me to fix that

Comment: @Frankenstein Change the `\def\l@subsubsubsection{...}` lines to `\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{9em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{15em}{6em}}` choose the second and third arguments appropriately.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina , perfect it's working now , can you explain what this line \def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{9em}{4em}}  does , i think it defines the margin for each section , subsection etc. thnaks

Comment: @Frankenstein `\l@<name>` is the command in charge of typesetting entries of type `<name>` in a list such as the ToC, the LoF, the LoT. `\@dottedtocline` is a kernel command producing the actual entry format (number, title/caption, leading dots, page number). First argument: level for `<name>`; second argument indentation from the left margin; third argument: space reserved for the number.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina is it just me or does the counter still not reset for numbered paragraphs? 3.1.3.2.4 does not reset to 3.1.3.3.1 Sadly because I got really excited that this code might be perfect for what I need.

Comment: I tried this, but it suppresses all section numbers throughout my document! Could it be related to the specific document class I'm using for a journal paper? It's one from Springer: `\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}`.

Comment: It seems to create a clash with the `algorithm` package, what can I do to deal with that as far as I need both such a `subsubsubsection` visible on the table of contents and some algorithms ? Will the `titlesec` option create subsubsubsection visible in it ?

Comment: @dinosaur same for me. The solution does *not* work as expected.

Comment: How to remove the indentation of the subparagraph in this solution?

Comment: My bookmark for paragraph and subparagraph are at the same level, I tried `bookmarksdepth=7` in `hyperref` setup, doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @Erik `\crefname{subsubsubsection}{section}{sections}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Why is this code changing the space after the "section" "subsection" and others ?
I think the line that modify that kind of format is \titlespacing* but you're only using that command with subsubsubsection... so I don't know why others are changing their vertical space after the title too

Answer (score 87):

Here's a solution that doesn't require the use of a specialized package such as `titlesec` or `sectsty`. (There's nothing wrong *per se*, obviously, with using packages to achieve a certain goal; nevertheless, I think it can be instructive at times to see how one can manipulate some of LaTeX's built-in commands directly.)

If you use the `article` document class, the default appearance of the output of the commands `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph` is set up as follows:

```
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                {-1em}%
                {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

To make the `\paragraph` command behave more like the `\subsubsection` command, but with less vertical spacing above and below the sectioning header line(s), you could modify the `\paragraph` command to make its output behave as if it were a "subsubsubsection". The following MWE illustrates a possible setup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A}
\subsection{B}
\subsubsection{C1}
\paragraph{D1}
\paragraph{D2}
\subsubsection{C2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us how we can make the font, say, italic?

Comment: @KutalmisBercin - Should it be "just" italic, or should it be bold **and** italic? Please advise.

Comment: Just italic, if possible.

Comment: @KutalmisBercin - In the `\renewcommand` instruction, change `\bfseries` to `\itshape`.

Comment: Don't how to make an extra vote up; hence, many thanks.

Comment: I wish we could give more than one vote for an extraordinary answer. Thank you so much for solving this issue.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum - Many thanks for your *very nice* compliment! It's much appreciated. :-)

Comment: This answer does not work. 
It gives an undefined control sequence error.

Comment: @Toma - I apologize profusely for the fact that my mind-reading skills are simply non-existent. Unless you tell me *which* control sequence is undefined, I am in no position to offer any kind of advice on how to fix the issue you say you've encountered. FWIW, if I compile the code above, which I posted more than 9 years ago, with a current TeX distribution (MacTeX2021, to be specific), I experience no problems whatsoever.

Comment: No need, the answer below works fine.
Your answer might well be dated. Just letting people know it is.

Comment: @Toma - Your assertions that my answer "does not work" and "might well be dated" are both *dead wrong*. Just letting people know how weak and unfounded your assertions are.

Answer (score 23):

I know this is an old question, but I found it with Google and I think the solutions are too complicated.

For me this is the easiest way for a subsubsubsection:

```
\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
```

After this it's possible to use

```
\subsubsubsection{Navigator}
```

Comment: That's not really a good solution. It does not provide an optional argument for `\subsubsubection` but allows a page break immediately after the heading. Do not use this! Instead use one of the solutions from the answers above, if your class does not provide its own interface for defining such commands. The solutions are less complicated than you may think.

Comment: Nevertheless, for me this solution worked better than either of those above. The solution by Gonzalo Medina caused side effects like removing numbering from the PDF table of contents. I was already using paragraphs and wanted them to retain the default formatting, so Mico's solution was not ideal. Furthermore the mentioned deficiencies of Daniel's solution didn't apply: I wasn't using the optional argument of `\subsubsubsection`, and I was already having to work around the fact that the default heuristics to avoid page breaks after headings don't work reliably.

Comment: @Daira I think if you simply change `\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}`, paragraphs will be numbered in the table of contents. I don't think this is a flaw of Gonzalo Medina's solution, you just need to change a few numbers in his code.

Comment: Maybe not most elegant, but practical. Thanks

Comment: @Horbaje - Any purported solution that permits serious typographic malpractice -- such as allowing a page break immediately after the sectioning header, without issuing even a whimper of a warning -- should not be labelled "practical". "Dangerous" and "asking for trouble" would be more suitable adjectives, for sure.

Comment: That works for me. Tnx.

Comment: It works, when the other answers don't.
I don't know what the problem of the people commenting against this solution is.
Many thanks

Comment: @Toma - As with the comment you left below [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60218/5001), your claim that "it works, when the other answers don't" is not helpful. Your condescending addition, "I don't know what the problem of the people commenting against this solution is", merely demonstrates that you've made no noticeable effort to understand the serious drawbacks of the `\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}` approach.

Answer (score 15):

The are two good answers to show how to add a new level section or modify  an existing one. But both are assuming some basic knowledge of LaTeX and typography. Maybe these remarks can help to new users to decide when these or a similar approaches are the best solution.

> requires many levels of sectioning

The best solution could be reconsider that premise. Is it really true? Sometimes (e.g., legal documents, huge technical reports), but often is not an imperative requirement but the insane decision of mimic this or that monstrous thesis. Defaults levels are more than enough in most documents.

> I have sections, subsections and subsubsections ...
>
> I see that the \paragraph command is used  ...

It seems that you are using the `article` class, because you mention only this four heading levels, so the first question is
[How many levels of nested subsections can the article class support?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163676/how-many-levels-of-nested-subsections-can-the-article-class-support) Short anwser: there are **six**, not four levels of sectioning.

Moreover, the book-like classes than allow one more level
(`\chapter`), so you can have at least **seven** levels (-1 to 5, not 1 to 7) without effort. Using the `memoir` class you have also the option that chapters behave as sections:

```
\documentclass[article,oneside]{memoir}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} % Note that part is -1 level !
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\newpage\relax
\tableofcontents*
\part{Part}
\endgroup
\chapter{Chapter} Text. 
\section{Section} Text.
\subsection{Subsection} Text.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection} Text.
\paragraph{Paragraph} Text.
\subparagraph{Subparagraph} Text.
\end{document}
```

Need more? For a deeper structuring of your contents you can use also the starred versions of sectioning commands (`\subsection*`, etc.),  environment lists (`enumerate`, `itemize`,`description`, or a custom `list`) and a judicious use of blank lines (`\par`) to remark the content structure (often some people break paragraphs only to avoid long chunks of texts).

Still need [More section headings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30997/more-section-headings) Well, it's up to you. Then go to other answers, or follow the last link for a ridiculously high number of sectional levels.

Comment: Just to offer an actual example that I have laying around in my computer, please refer to section 17.5.16.3.2.2.1. (Continuous Phase) of the ANSYS Fluent Theory Guide =)

Answer (score 12):

[This very excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60218) can also very easily be expanded to add `\subsubsubsection` and `\subsubsubsubsection` commands:

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsubsubsection{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\subsubsubsection{subsubsubsection}
\subsubsubsubsection{subsubsubsubsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP. It is just a comment on someone else's answer.

Comment: That was the perfect solution for me. Thanks for sharing @finefoot 

Answer (score 11):

With KOMA-Script classes you do not need nor should use an extra package to redefine sectioning commands or define new sectioning levels. And you don't need and should not use low level code.

These classes provide command `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to reconfigure existing sectioning commands. For example to have a `\paragraph` that does not produce a title at the beginning of the paragraph (a so called *catch phrase* or *runin title*) but a displayed title, you can use:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[runin=false,afterskip=1ex,afterindent=false]{paragraph}
```

Option `runin=false` is used to make it a displayed instead of a runin title. `afterskip=1ex` makes a vertical skip of 1ex after the heading. `afterindent=false` prevents the following paragraph to be indented.

So the result would be something like:

[image]

If you need a paragraph number, just add

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\paragraphnumdepth}
```

very ease with KOMA-Script. You don't need to remember the numeric value.

You can do a similar change for `\subparagraph`:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[indent=0pt,runin=false,afterskip=1ex,afterindent=false]{subparagraph}
```

Here additionally `indent=0pt` is used to remove the default indent of subparagraph titles.

If this is not enough, you can even define a `\subsubparagraph` very easily:

```
\DeclareNewSectionCommand[style=section,level=\numexpr \subparagraphnumdepth+1\relax,runin=false,beforeskip=1ex,afterskip=0pt,afterindent=false]{subsubparagraph}
```

[image]

See the KOMA-Script manual for the meaning of all the options and how to use them and all the other available options.

BTW: After defining `\subsubparagraph` there is also a `\subsubparagraphnumdepth` (and even a `\subsubparagraphtocdepth`) that can be used to change `secnumdepth`.

Comment: If you're using the KOMA class, you could use the jura package which provides for great flexibility in sub-sectioning.

Comment: @user26732 Which jura package do you mean. I know [the `jura` class](https://ctan.org/pkg/jura). I also know [`scrjura`](https://ctan.org/pkg/scrjura), but that one does not support sub-sectioning but clauses.

Comment: Jura class, not package.

Comment: @user26732 But `jura` class is not a KOMA-Script class nor a class from KoMa. And it also does not provide most of the features of a KOMA-Script class. So I still don't understand your comment. Maybe you should just add one more answer showing, why using `jura` class could be a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This solution might help other folks looking for a quick walkaround:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}  
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]  
{\normalfont\bf\large\centering\singlespace}{\chaptertitlename\ 
\thechapter}{14pt}{}  
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-35pt}{0pt}{} 

\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\normalfont\bf\em}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{} 

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]
{\normalfont\em}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]
{\normalfont\em}{\thesubsubsection}{12pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}{}

\end{document}
```