# subsubsubparagraph

Tags: sectioning

In a LaTeX `article` we 
have `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`,  `\paragraph`, `\subparagraph`.
What do I do if I want to go deeper and want to use
`\subsubparagraph` or `\subsubsubparagraph`and avoid the arbitrary restriction
imposed by LaTeX?

Or what if I want to do instead `\subsubsubsubsubsubsubsection`?

Comment: Do not do this :-)

Comment: Seriously: in principal you can define such things, but in a real document it's extremely unlikely you need them.

Comment: Legal documents may be subject to this structure...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below `\subsubsection`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209/5764)

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Werner No. No legal documents need 12-13 levels. I once participated in the writing of a proposition (bill) from the Government to the Parliament (in Norway) to reform the tax law. Near 600 pages, but we only need four levels. If you really need twelve levels, you really need to rewrite your text.