# How to remove the red boxes around toc

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, framed

This is in with regards to the below post

[How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection)

The code works flawlessly. But do I remove the red frame boxes which cover the entries in table of content?

Sorry about the stupid question but I am new to latex and just trying to learn ...

MB

Comment: The boxes are added by the `hyperref` package,  and indicates that the toc entries are hyperlinks. Add `hidelinks` as an option to `hyperref`, i.e. `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - make this into an answer, please.

Comment: the boxes will not show in the printed version of the document, and option `colorlinks=true` allows to use colors rather than boxes.

Comment: @Mico There's bound to be a duplicate question somewhere, I just didn't have time to find it.