# Extra section level

Tags: sectioning

I used the following code to add an extra level of section:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {2.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\textit}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC
```

How can I remove the space that is specified in the figure?

[image: Figure]

Comment: What class are you using? Paragraphs are not numbered by default but the command `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` should be enough to number it. The default has no space before the number.

Comment: Thank you Sigur, 

I removed 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {2.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\textit}}
\makeatother

and the problem has been solved :)

Comment: If you want to change the font used there you can copy the original code from the class (e.g. `report.cls`) and then you only change the final part (e.g. `\textbf`).

Comment: Related: [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below `\subsubsection`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\textit` takes an argument, which is not properly used in this instance. Instead you need to use a font swith - `\itshape`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
            {-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
            {2.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
            {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC
\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{7}

\section{A section}
\subsection{A sub-section}
\subsubsection{A sub-sub-section}
\subsubsubsection{A sub-sub-sub-section}

\end{document}
```

For information on the parameters in `\@startsection`, see [Where can I find help files or documentation for commands like `\@startsection` for LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31780/5764)