# Adding a sectioning level with titleclass and tocdepth

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec

I want to add a `subchapter` sectioning level, between `chapter` and `section`.
I use the `\titleclass` command from `titlesec` package.

According to `titlesec` documentation, `\titleclass{\subchapter}{straight}[\chapter]` should set the level of `subchapter` to 1, and increase  by 1 the levels below (`section` of level 2, `subsection` of level 3, etc).

However, the following example :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\subchapter}{straight}[\chapter]
\newcounter{subchapter}
\titleformat{\subchapter}[block]{}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subchapter}{1pc}{*4}{*2.3}
\titlecontents{subchapter}[1.5em]{}{}{\hspace*{-2.3em}}{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{.}\contentspage} %bad formatting, but only here to produce a content line in ToC

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter one}

\subchapter{Subchapter one}

\section{Section one}
\subsection{A subsection}

\section{Section two}

\end{document}
```

produces a ToC showing both `subchapter` and `section`, meaning  that the level of `section` is still equal to 1.

I also tried to add

```
\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@section{2}
\makeatother
```

as suggested in [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection),
but it does nothing.

What am I missing?

Note that for now, I do not care about the formatting of the ToC and can manage this by myself later, I am only interested in the levels of the different sectioning titles.

Answer (score 1):

The basic command `\titlecontents` is defined in the [`titlesec`](https://ctan.kako-dev.de/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package as (see p.14):

```
\titlecontents{〈section〉}[〈left〉]{〈above-code〉}{〈numbered-entry-format〉}{〈numberless-entry-format〉}{〈filler-page-format〉}[〈below-code〉
```

I your case the option `{〈numbered-entry-format〉}` is "empty" , that is, it seems to be undefined. Therefore, after compiling my output does not show any subchapter number:

[image]

`\contentslabel`or `\thecontentslabel` print the subchapter number:

- `\contentslabel{2.3em}`:

  [image]
- `\thecontentslabel\enspace`:

  [image]

Without defining the option `{〈numbered-entry-format〉}` but combining it with the  macro `\dottedcontents`, it also prints the subchapter number:

[image]

Nevertheless, in all the cases there is a problem with the level; but the manual says (p. 10):

"***If the chapter level is 0, then the subchapter one is 1; the levels below are increased by one (section is 2, subsection is 3, and so on).***"

This issue is addressed in `GitHub` as [\titleclass doesn't increase levels below](https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/2) and it stills open by Javier Bezos, the author of `\titlsec`.

---

---

---

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\subchapter}{straight}[\chapter]
\newcounter{subchapter}
\titleformat{\subchapter}[block]{}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subchapter}{1pc}{*4}{*2.3}

%------------ together
\titlecontents{subchapter}[1.5em]{}{}{\hspace*{-2.3em}}{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{.}\contentspage} %bad formatting, but only here to produce a content line in ToC
\dottedcontents{subchapter}[1cm]{}{2.3em}{1pc}
%------------

%------with \contentslabel ------
%\titlecontents{subchapter}[1.5em]{}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}{\hspace*{-2.3em}}{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{.}\contentspage}

%------with \thecontentslabel ------
%\titlecontents{subchapter}[1.5em]{}{\thecontentslabel\enspace}{\hspace*{-2.3em}}{\titlerule*[0.75pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Chapter one}

    \subchapter{Subchapter one}

    \section{Section one}
    \subsection{A subsection}

    \section{Section two}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue if one uses the standard LaTeX `\tableofcontents` construction (rather than loading `titletoc`).  My conclusion is that inserting a new section level via `titlesec` changes the level as far as `secnumdepth` is concerned, but doesn't affect the table of contents commands.

The following is my solution:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{titletoc}

\titleclass{\subchapter}{straight}[\chapter]
\newcounter{subchapter}
\titleformat{\subchapter}[block]{}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subchapter}{1pc}{*4}{*2.3}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\l@subchapter}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}

% The following redefines the \l@section so that \tableofcontents thinks
% that a section has Level 2, rather than Level 1.
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}

\makeatother

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter one}
\subchapter{Subchapter one}
\section{Section one}
\subsection{A subsection}
\section{Section two}

\end{document}
```

I don't know what the correction is if you use `titletoc`, but I presume it is analogous.