# Correct hierarchy levels of PDF bookmarks for custom section \subsubsubsection

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks, sections-paragraphs

I **had** to to define a `\subsubsubsection` for a technical document (I know it is highly criticised). I believe I inspired myself from this [alternative answer to *How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60218/31665) at that time (I couldn't use the package `titlesec`, but I can't remember the reason).

However, the hierarchy in the PDF bookmarks is messed up: subsubsubsection is shown as level 1 instead of 4, even though I tell `\@startsection` it's level 4 in the definition of `\subsubsubsection`. I wrongly expected this to handle PDF bookmarks implicitly as well.

How do I tell the package which is handling the PDF bookmarks (I guess `hyperref`) that the `\subsubsubsection` is level 4? Or alternatively as a suboptimal workaround, how do I tell `\subsubsubsection` not to show up in the PDF bookmarks at all (remember, setting `bookmarksdepth<4` is not working, since it is ignoring that it is level 4).

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsubsection}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}

\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\it\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\newcommand*{\l@subsubsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{4}{11em}{5em}}  
\renewcommand*{\l@paragraph}{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
\renewcommand*{\l@subparagraph}{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{7em}}

\newcommand{\subsubsubsectionmark}[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\subsubsubsection{SubsubsubSection}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if it suits your needs, but maybe the bookmark package (that fixes some strange behaviors of hyperref) can be useful

Comment: latex provides section levels below subsubsection by default, why insert a new one in the middle of the sequence? Do you really need all 6 levels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is really needed, use `bookmark` package, say `depth=3` as option (i.e. only down to `subsubsection`) and (more important!!!):

You've to specify the level in which the new `subsubsubsection` has to be hooked to:

`\newcommand{\toclevel@subsubsubsection}{4}`

This way you inform `hyperref` (and the `bookmark`) package, that `subsubsubsection` counters are on level 4.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[depth=3]{bookmark}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
%\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4}



\makeatletter

\newcommand{\toclevel@subsubsubsection}{4}
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsubsection}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}


\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}}

\newcommand{\subsubsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\it\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}

\newcommand*{\l@subsubsubsection}{\@dottedtocline{4}{11em}{5em}}  
\renewcommand*{\l@paragraph}{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
\renewcommand*{\l@subparagraph}{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{7em}}

\newcommand{\subsubsubsectionmark}[1]{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\phantomsection
\subsubsubsection{SubsubsubSection}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I add this as a follow-up answer for those (like me) having a similar setup and problem. I created a subsubparagraph (level 6) that works fine in TOC but PDF bookmarks resets it to chapter (level 1) along with every header that follows it. I'm using PDFLaTex. To fix the problem, I only needed to add the previous answer's \toclevel solution modified for subsubparagraph, (`\newcommand{\toclevel@subsubparagraph}{6}`) to my `\@startsection` as in the MWE. Pic: left, the problem: subsubsection put at chapter level; right pic, as fixed.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen]{hyperref} %,pdfview=Fit %to open bookmark to top of page
\usepackage{bookmark}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6} %make sure my subsects all numbered to lowest level
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6} %tell toc to include all numbered subsects as above
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]% counter for numbering
\renewcommand{\thesubsubparagraph}%               how to display 
{\thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}%  numbering
\newcommand{\subsubparagraph}{\@startsection
    {subsubparagraph}%
    {6}%
    {0pt}%
    {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}% %\baselineskip
    {1.5ex plus 0.2ex}% %\0.5\baselineskip
    {\usefont{OT1}{phv}{c}{sc}\selectfont\fontsize{9}{9}}} %\scshape}}
\newcommand{\toclevel@subsubparagraph}{6} %added to fix pdf bookmark hierarchy
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{10em}{5em}}% for toc
\newcommand{\subsubparagraphmark}[1]{}% for page headers
\makeatother


\begin{document}
     \part{TEST}
     \chapter{chaptest}
     kdkd
     \section{sectest}
     kdkd
     \subsection{subsectest}
     ddk
     \subsubsection{subsubsectest}
     dkdk
     \paragraph{paratest}
     dkdk
     \subparagraph{subpartest}
     dkdk
     \subsubparagraph{subsubpartest}
     dkdkd
     \paragraph{postssptest}
     dkdk
     \subsubsection{postssstest}
     kdkd
     \chapter{postchaptest}
     kdkd
\end{document}
```

[image]