# Section numbers disappear

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I don't have enough reputation to write a comment, so I have to ask a separate question instead.

I tried Gonzalo Medina's answer to this question: [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection)

It seems to work fine, except that section headings don't have numbers, as can be seen on my screenshot. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[image]

Edit: I am talking about Gonzalo Medina's second solution in the link above.

Comment: Be sure to have an up-to-date version of `titlesec`; one version had a bug that in some cases prevented section numbers to appear.

Comment: There are two solutions Gonzalo Medina's answer. Which one are you using?

Comment: @samcarter The second one.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you've encountered. Please tells us which version of the `titlesec` package you have on your system. On my system (TeXlive2016, fully updated), I found the following information in the log file: `titlesec 2016/03/21 v2.10.2`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is solved with a software update

Comment: I agree with @egreg. Where is the button to do that?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by egreg in the comments of the question, the solution was as simple as updating the packages. I didn't know that the texlive package available in the Ubuntu repository was not the most up to date. I followed the instructions on the link below to get the most updated version of texlive and now it works.

http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: I once had `ubuntu` installed on my laptop and I was highly disappointed by its TeX distribution packages. I deleted that installation and never tried again, but I can hardly remember that anybody recommends using the ubuntu TL packages. Just use the installation provided by TeXLive (i.e. the net installation)