# section command in Latex

Tags: sectioning

I am a new user of latex, I got a template to write my thesis in Latex. But in this template the section command does allow me to make more sub-sections. with the help of `\section` and `\subsection` command I can only go till 3 subsection. For example:

```
1. Main section
1.1 first subsection
1.1.1 first sub-sub section
```

but it does not allow me to do this

```
1.1.1.1 first sub sub sub section
```

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This is normal: `\subsubsubsection` is not implemented in LaTeX. You can use `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` instead (and adjust their numbering accordingly). If you still need more sectioning levels, you have two solutions: 1) reconsider if you *really* need so much levels, or 2) see already asked questions like [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209/64454)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please check with your university whether there is a limit to the depth of sub*sections; if the style doesn't offer it, it may be because the university doesn't want it. Depending on the document class, you may have `\chapter` and `\part` above `\section` and `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` below `\subsubsection`. Moreover, it is often considered confusing to have too deep nesting. If after all these considerations you still want to have more subsections, please tell us which document class you will use (e.g. link to the thesis template).