# How to create subsubparagraph and subsubsubparagraph?

Tags: koma-script, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to create a subsubparagraph and subsubsubparagraph. Subsubsubparagraph is working fine, but subsubparagraph is giving me strange results in my Table of Contents.

Here is my Code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter

\titleclass{\subsubparagraph}{straight}[\subparagraph]
\titleformat{\subsubparagraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragraph}.\arabic{subparagraph}.\arabic{subsubparagraph}}{1em}{}

\titlespacing{\subsubparagraph}{0pt}{-3.25ex plus-1ex minus-.2ex}{1.25ex plus .1ex}

\newcounter{subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]

\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{0pt}{-3.25ex plus-1ex minus-.2ex}{1.25ex plus .1ex}
\titleclass{\subsubsubparagraph}{straight}[\subparagraph]

\titleformat{\subsubsubparagraph}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragraph}.\arabic{subparagraph}.\arabic{subsubparagraph}.\arabic{subsubparagraph}}{1em}{}

\titlespacing{\subsubsubparagraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus-1ex minus-.2ex}{1.25ex plus .1ex}

\newcounter{subsubsubparagraph}[subsubparagraph]

\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph {\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.\arabic{paragraph}.\arabic{subparagraph}.\arabic{subsubparagraph}}% 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{8}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{8}

\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{7}{12em}{2em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{8}{17em}{2em}}


\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{10}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{10}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph}
\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
\subsubparagraph{Subsubparagraph}
\subsubsubparagraph{Subsubparagraph}

\end{document}
```

The title of the subsubparagraph is overlapping with the numbering.
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is similar in nature to [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below `\subsubsection`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209/5764)

Comment: What happens when you change some of the lengths in your definition of `\l@subsubparagraph`? That seems to be the one causing the overlapping problem.

Comment: Is this really necessary? Wouldn't it be better to use a `book` - structure class (or `memoir` with its `book` level) in order to have 7 or even 8 levels of structures (I never needed more than 5, I think, yet, in my 'typo' life) instead of inventing such things?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that package `titlesec` breaks some of the KOMA-Script features. So it is not recommended to use this package together with `scrartcl`.

You can use `\DeclareNewSectionCommands` and `\RedeclareSectionCommand`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}[2016/05/10]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareNewSectionCommands[
  style=section,
  level=\subparagraphnumdepth+1,
  beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
  afterskip=1.25ex plus .1ex,
  counterwithin=subparagraph,
  font={},
  indent=0pt,
  toclevel=\subparagraphtocdepth+1,
  tocnumwidth=6em
]{subsubparagraph,subsubsubparagraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=12em
]{subsubparagraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=14em
]{subsubsubparagraph}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsubparagraphnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsubparagraphtocdepth}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Text
\paragraph{Paragraph}
Text
\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
Text
\subsubparagraph{Subsubparagraph}
Text
\subsubsubparagraph{Subsubsubparagraph}
Text
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see in the image `paragraph` and `subparagraph` are inline headings.
A negative value of `afterskip` sets a horizontal skip resulting in an inline heading. So if the headings for the new defined levels should also be inline headings, use `afterskip=-1em`. But if there should be vertical space after the `paragraph` and `subparagraph` change their `afterskip` to a positiv value, eg:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=1.25ex plus .1ex
]{paragraph,subparagraph}
```