# How to get paragraph and subparagraph not to be inline headings

Tags: koma-script

I use KOMA-Script and the code example from the answere of "esdd"

[How to create subsubparagraph and subsubsubparagraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380564/how-to-create-subsubparagraph-and-subsubsubparagraph?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

**How to get paragraph and subparagraph not to be inline headings?**

Answer (score 1):

A negative value of afterskip sets a horizontal skip resulting in an inline heading. If `paragraph` and `subparagraph` should not be inline headings then change their afterskip to a positiv value, eg:

Set `afterskip` to a positiv value:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=1.25ex plus .1ex
]{paragraph,subparagraph}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[parskip=full]{scrartcl}[2016/05/10]
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=1.25ex plus .1ex
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\DeclareNewSectionCommands[
  style=section,
  level=\subparagraphnumdepth+1,
  beforeskip=-3.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex,
  afterskip=1.25ex plus .1ex,
  counterwithin=subparagraph,
  font={},
  indent=0pt,
  toclevel=\subparagraphtocdepth+1,
  tocnumwidth=6em
]{subsubparagraph,subsubsubparagraph}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=12em
]{subsubparagraph}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocindent=14em
]{subsubsubparagraph}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsubparagraphnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsubparagraphtocdepth}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Text
\paragraph{Paragraph}
Text
\subparagraph{Subparagraph}
Text
\subsubparagraph{Subsubparagraph}
Text
\subsubsubparagraph{Subsubsubparagraph}
Text
\end{document}
```