# Change paragraph TOC style

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titlesec, paragraphs

i'm modifying my LaTeX template, and I used [the code from this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60212/170959) to modify a few things in my TOC.
Currently i have this code [Modified in order to make it compilable, using the same libraries my main file uses]:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}  %% be sure to specify the option 'hyphens'
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarksnumbered,breaklinks, colorlinks = true]{hyperref}
\graphicspath{{Capturas/}}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{listings,lstautogobble}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Commando}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  breaklines=true,
  autogobble=true
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% COMANDOS%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% SHADOW IMAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}

\def\shadowshift{3pt,-3pt}
\def\shadowradius{6pt}

\colorlet{innercolor}{black!60}
\colorlet{outercolor}{gray!02}

\newcommand\drawshadow[1]{
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{shadow}
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[outercolor,inner color=innercolor,outer color=outercolor] ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) circle (\shadowradius);
        \shade[top color=innercolor,bottom color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[left color=innercolor,right color=outercolor] ($(#1.south east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[bottom color=innercolor,top color=outercolor] ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);
        \shade[outercolor,right color=innercolor,left color=outercolor] ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(-\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,-\shadowradius/2)$);
        \filldraw ($(#1.south west)+(\shadowshift)+(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$) rectangle ($(#1.north east)+(\shadowshift)-(\shadowradius/2,\shadowradius/2)$);

\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{shadow} 
\pgfsetlayers{shadow,main}


\newcommand\shadowimage[2][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[#1]{#2}};
\drawshadow{image}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}


%%%%%%%%%%%%% SUBSUBSUBSECTION %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\setmarginsrb{2.5 cm}{1.5 cm}{2.5 cm}{1.5 cm}{0.7 cm}{1 cm}{0.7 cm}{1 cm}

\title{Ataques XSS}                 % Titulo
\author{Àlex Coronas Altemir \\[0.1ex] Andrés Igual}    % Autores
\date{\today}                       % Fecha


\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue!50!red,
  urlcolor=blue!70!magenta,
  citecolor=blue!70!magenta
}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vspace*{0.0 cm}
    \textsc{\LARGE Monlau C.E}\\[2.0 cm]    % Nombre Centro
    \textsc{\Large 2 ASIX}\\[0.5 cm]                %  Curso
    \textsc{\large M11 - Seguretat i alta disponibilitat}\\[0.5 cm]     % MODULO
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
    { \huge \bfseries \thetitle}\\
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[1.5 cm]

    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{center} \large
            \emph{Autor/es:}\\
            \theauthor \linebreak
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}\\[2 cm]

    {\large \thedate}\\[2 cm]

    \vfill

\end{titlepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begingroup
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
\tableofcontents
\endgroup
\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\end{document}
```

Wich works as I want, except for one little thing, i don't want dotted lines for my paragraphs. I've been messing with `\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}` to see if I can remove them but i don't seem to be able to do it.

Can someone provide some help?

EDIT:
I added more code to made it compilable and use te same libraries as I do. Also, I ignore wheter this is important or not, but everything inside the below the COMMANDS comment until y set the margins is in another file that I input.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Oh. Sure! I have this on a separate tex file that I input into my main file, but i'll change the code i posted in order to make it compilable