# New title class doesn't increase counter

Tags: sectioning, counters, titlesec

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and need to create a subsubsubsection in a document. After looking around I found that it could be done with `titlesec`. I've followed all instructions I've been able to find but it stil doesn't work as I desire.

The subsubsubsection shows up in the table of contents and the counter does work when using the `\setcounter{}{}` and it's also reset every subsubsection, but for some reason the counter does not increase with new subsubsubsections nor is `thesubsubsubsection` displayed in the table of contents or the text.

Below is the code and the document. In the end the table of contents will probably just display 2 levels, so I don't really care about the looks there at the moment. It is just included to show that the subsubsubsection is recognised in some way.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsubsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsubsection}{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}{0mm}{0mm}{0mm}[0mm]
\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}{\small}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section one}
\subsection{Subsection one}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one}
\subsubsubsection{Subsubsubsection one}
\thesubsubsubsection\\
\setcounter{subsubsubsection}{3}
\thesubsubsubsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsection two}
\subsubsubsection{Subsubsubsection one}
\thesubsubsubsection\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Relative: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection ... You have to add the command `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` to get it work

Comment: you don't need to define new counters, article class already has level 4 and 5 headings, the commands are `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the value of `secnumdepth` (by default sectioning titles are numbered up to level 3 – the level of subsubsections). You also should have to set the layout of subsubsubsections in the table of contents via `titletoc`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsubsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}%[subsubsection]
\counterwithin{subsubsubsection}{subsubsection}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}{0mm}{0mm}{0mm}[0mm]
\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}{\small}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section one}
\subsection{Subsection one}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection one}
\subsubsubsection{Subsubsubsection one}
\thesubsubsubsection\\
\setcounter{subsubsubsection}{3}
\thesubsubsubsection
\subsubsection{Subsubsection two}
\subsubsubsection{Subsubsubsection one}
\thesubsubsubsection

\end{document}
```

[image]