# How to set all titles levels of a document following strict rules?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting

I'm writing a document with very specific rules:

- Section: 14 pt, bold, uppercase
- Subsection: 12 pt, bold, uppercase
- Subsubsection: 12 pt, bold
- Paragraph: 12 pt
- Document spacing: 1.5
- Space between paragraphs: a line
- Space after titles: a line
- Numbering: Up to level 4 (paragraph)
- Numbering: space-space (1 - Text)

Here is an example:

[image]

Until now, I changed the titles font and size with `sectsty` package, the document spacing with `linespread{1.3}`, the numbering up to level 4.

I still need

- to add the hyphen in the numbering
- to set the space between paragraphs, and titles and paragraphs
- to add a line break after level 4 (paragraph)

How can I do this using the least amount of packages

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\partfont{\centering}
\chapterfont{\raggedright\Large\MakeUppercase}
\sectionfont{\raggedright\large\MakeUppercase}
\subsectionfont{\raggedright\normalsize\MakeUppercase}
\subsubsectionfont{\raggedright}
\paragraphfont{\raggedright\normalfont}
%%%%%%%%%%
\linespread{1.3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the `titlesec` package.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection. I think you'd be better served with KOMA-Script (see on of the answers at the link above).

Comment: Every time I see something like this, I know it's the dreaded ABNT-customization challenge.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote,

```
I still need    
    to add the hyphen in the numbering
    to set the space between paragraphs, and titles and paragraphs
    to add a line break after level 4 (paragraph)
```

I will assume that you will be using the `article` document class.

For the first item, I suggest you insert the following instructions in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\space- }
\makeatother
```

Incidentally, should you need to insert an "en-dash" rather than a hyphen, simply replace `-` with `--` in the preceding code block.

For the second item, I suggest you load the `parskip` package with the options `skip=1\baselineskip` and `indent`. (Specifying the latter option preserves the non-zero default indentation of paragraphs.

Before turning to the third item, I would like to suggest that you

- replace `\usepackage{mathptmx}` with `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` (the `mathptmx` package is really olde,
- replace `\linespread{1.3}` with `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.3}` (don't manipulate a low-level parameter such as `\linespread` directly), and
- replace `\sectionfont{\raggedright\large\MakeUppercase}` with `\sectionfont{\raggedright\fontsize{14}{16.8}`. (If the main document font size is `12pt`, then `\large` corresponnds to `14.4pt`, *not* `14pt`.)

Finally, regarding the objective of having a line break after `\paragraph`-level headers: I suggest you add the following code to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
    {\z@}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
    {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont\normalsize}}
\makeatother
```

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

%%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{sectsty} 
\partfont{\centering}
%%\chapterfont{\raggedright\Large\MakeUppercase} % not needed
%%\sectionfont{\raggedright\large\MakeUppercase}
\sectionfont{\raggedright\fontsize{14}{16.8}\selectfont\MakeUppercase}
\subsectionfont{\raggedright\normalsize\MakeUppercase}
\subsubsectionfont{\raggedright}
\paragraphfont{\raggedright\normalfont}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

%%\linespread{1.3} % don't manipulate this macro directly
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3} % BTW: why not "1.5"?


%% And here's the all-new code:
\makeatletter

% Extra space between paragraphs:
\usepackage[indent,skip=1\baselineskip]{parskip}

% Insert "-" (dash) between sectioning numbers and text:
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\space- }

% Line break after \paragraph-level headers:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
    {\z@}{-3.25ex\@plus -0.75ex \@minus -.1ex}%
    {1ex \@plus .2ex}{\normalfont\normalsize}}

\makeatother  % end of new-code block


\begin{document}
\section{Heading on level 1 (Section)}
\subsection{Heading on level 2 (Subsection)}
\subsubsection{Heading on level 3 (Subsubsection)}
\paragraph{Heading on level 4 (Paragraph)}
\lipsum[1-2] % filler text
\end{document}
```