# Add automatic titles like \chapter, \section, \subsection etc

Tags: sectioning, formatting

Is it possible to add titles after \subparagraph?
Latex has 7 levels of titles (from \part to \subparagraph), but I need 9 of them.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209/134144 might be interesting

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX provides a generic command `\@startsection` for defining sectional divisions.

```
\@startsection{name}{level}{indent}{beforeskip}{afterskip}{style}
```

where `name` is the name of the division, `level` is where it is in the hierarchy, `indent` is the space before the heading, the skips are the spaces before and after the title (if `\afterskip` is negative then the title will be run-in), and `style` is how it should be typeset. The `level` of a subparagraph is 5.

For two levels below `\subparagraph`, call them, say, `\clause` and `\subclause` they will be 6 and 7. You need new counters for the numbering.

```
\newcounter{clause}[subparagraph]  % (6)
\newcounter{subclause}[clause]     % (7)
\renewcommand{\theclause}{\thesubpargraph.\arabic{clause}}
\renewcommand{\thesubclause}{\theclause.\arabic{subclause}
```

Now here is a possible definition for the `\clause` division:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\clause}{\@startsection%
  {clause}{6}{<some length>} % name, level, indent
  {<some length>} % beforeskip
  {<some length>} % afterskip
  {\normalfont\normalsize\scshape} % style, small caps
}
```

It is up to you how you want your new sectional divisions to look. Good luck.