# \paragraph and \subparagraph formatting after creating a \subsubsubsection

Tags: formatting, sections-paragraphs

I have some issues formatting \paragraph and \subparagraph after creating a \subsubsubsection as found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209/134144).

As you can see on my code, I am trying to have this shape for my \paragraph and \subparagraph titles :

A. Paragraph title
1° Subparagraph title

On my case, **I cannot add the "." and the "°"** even though I have written this :

```
% **************************
% A. --> \paragraph
% **************************

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Alph{paragraph}}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]{\fontsize{11}{12} \selectfont}{\fontsize{13}{12} \selectfont \theparagraph. \\}{1em}{}

% **************************
% 1° --> \subparagraph
% **************************

\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[block] {\bfseries\LARGE}{\thesubparagraph ° \\}{1em}{}
```

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{librecaslon}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{supertabular}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.7}




% **************************
% **************************
% **************************
% Formatting titles
% **************************
% **************************
% **************************

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}

% **************************
% Function for \part and \chapter titles
% **************************

\newcommand\framethispage[1][1cm]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,line width=0.2pt]
    \draw([xshift=(#1),yshift=(-#1)]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=(#1),yshift=(#1)+2mm]current page.south west);%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,line width=0.2pt]
    \draw([xshift=(#1),yshift=(-#1)]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=(-#1)-2mm,yshift=(-#1)]current page.north east);%
}

% **************************
% Livre 1 --> \part
% **************************

\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\framethispage[2cm]
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
\else
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
\fi
{\parindent \z@ 
\interlinepenalty \@M
\normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\vspace{-9.5cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={anchor=base,inner sep=0pt}]
\node[my node] (center) {\fontsize{12}{12} \selectfont \text{Livre} \thepart};
\draw($(center.base)+(-1.9cm,-1ex)$)     -- ($(center.base)+(+1.9cm,-1ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\par\nobreak
\fi
\begin{center}
\fontsize{18}{12} \selectfont #2
\end{center}
\markboth{}{}\par}
\newpage
\@afterheading}
\makeatother



% **************************
% Partie 1 --> \chapter
% **************************

\makeatletter

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\framethispage[2cm]
\vspace{3.3cm}

{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[my node/.style={anchor=base,inner sep=0pt}]
\node[my node] (center) {\fontsize{12}{12} \selectfont \text{Partie} \thechapter};
\draw($(center.base)+(-1.9cm,-1ex)$) -- ($(center.base)+(+1.9cm,-1ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\par\nobreak
\fi
\interlinepenalty\@M
\begin{center}
\fontsize{18}{12} \selectfont #1\par\nobreak
\end{center}
\newpage
}}

\makeatother



% **************************
% TITRE n° --> \section
% **************************

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\fontsize{26}{12} \selectfont \filcenter}{\fontsize{13}{12} \selectfont \textsc{Titre}\
\thesection\\\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}\\}{1em}{}


% **************************
% Chapitre n° --> \subsection
% **************************

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\fontsize{24}{12} \selectfont\filcenter}{\fontsize{13}{12} \selectfont \textsc{Chapitre}\
\thesubsection\\\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}\\}{1em}{}

% **************************
% Section n° --> \subsubsection
% **************************

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block] {\sffamily}{SECTION\ \thesubsubsection}{0.3em}{\bfseries\fontsize{14}{12} \selectfont}[\vskip 0.5ex \titlerule]

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*4}{*4}


%*****
% I. --> \subsubsubsection
%*****

\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsubsection}{\Roman{subsubsubsection}}

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}[block]{\bfseries \fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont}
{\thesubsubsubsection.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}



%\titleformat{\paragraph}[block] {\bfseries\LARGE}{\theparagraph.}{1em}{}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother





% **************************
% A. --> \paragraph
% **************************

\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\Alph{paragraph}}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]{\fontsize{11}{12} \selectfont}{\fontsize{13}{12} \selectfont \theparagraph. \\}{1em}{}

% **************************
% 1° --> \subparagraph
% **************************

\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[block] {\bfseries\LARGE}{\thesubparagraph \text{°}}{1em}{}


%*****
% Définition du compteur
%*****
\newcounter{subpara}
\newcommand\numsubpara[1]{\par\refstepcounter{subpara} \thesubpara\text{.}\textbf{\space#1\space}\\}




\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsubsection{Test}
\subsubsubsection{Test}
\paragraph{Test}
\subparagraph{Test}
\numsubpara{Test}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result :

[image]

Comment: Note that titlesec replaces all the normal definitions, so you need to either ONLY use titlesec or not use it at all.

Comment: The link you provided points to a posting with 9 answers. Which one of the 9 answers did you adopt?

Comment: Hello @JohnKormylo : thank you for these informations. As you can see in my code, I have been formatting a lot \part and \chapter, adding two lines with tikz and an underline. In order to do this I have been redefining both of these functions. Is it possible to do this with titlesec ? If I have to use only titlesec and nothing else... But except for this "A." and "1°", everything is working perfectly !

Comment: Hello @Mico, thanks for getting back to me. As you can see in my code, I have been using what Gonzalo Medina calls "a fresh new sectional unit below \subsubsection, but above \paragraph"

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think I understand what you meant : since I write this "\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}" right after  reating subsubsubsection, I cannot use titlesec anymore ? If that's correct, how to add "." in this code ? \renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}% ?

Comment: On second thought, it might be possible to use titlesec for some but not all.  Check the aux file to see if titlesec changes \contentsline arguments.  You will probably also need a \l@subsubsubsection command.

Comment: Please read the tag description for titles. It is for titles, not titles.

Comment: Hello all, thank you for your answers. I am really sorry but I don't understand... "It is for titles, not titles" ? What is the tag description ?
I just need to add a dot "." after "A" on my paragraph... sorry about this ! My subsubsubsection is working perfectly well.

Comment: Do not use titles as a tag! See https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/titles/info