# Extra level sectioning with numbering

Tags: sectioning, subsection

By following the instructions given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection/60218#60218) and have modified them according to my need as follows:

```
\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\newcounter{paragraph}[subsubsubsection]
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph{\theparagraph.\arabic{subparagraph}}

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
```

However this gives an error as follows:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \c@paragraph already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

How do I make this work, with newcounter for paragraph as defined in above here.

This question might be a duplicate, if that is the case, then kindly point me to a resource.

Comment: Does it meet your needs simply to remove the line `\newcounter{paragraph}[subsubsubsection]`? That line appears verbatim in newer versions of `article.cls` already (assuming you're using that).

Comment: @frabjous "newer" here meaning any version of article.cls or article.sty since about 1983

Comment: while you can do this it seems unnecessarily complicated to insert the extra level (if you really need section 1.2.3.4.5.6 ????)  article already offers up to level 5 as `\subparagraph` so the simplest thing is to add a new level 6 as `\subsubparagraph` raher than having to redefine all the levels below your inserted level 4.

Comment: Thanks @frabjous and @david-carlislie for your comments. I really need section levels 1.2.3.4.5.6. Article is does provide numbering for paragraph, but it does not reset the numbering for paragraph. So I had added `\newcounter{paragraph}[subsubsubsection]`. With this in place the numbering works, except for the error, I have mentioned here.

Comment: I see. Yours has an extra `sub` compared to the line in document class. Try `\counterwithin{paragraph}{subsubsubsection}` instead of the line that's causing you trouble.

Comment: @frabjous Thanks so much! That worked! Really appreciate your input and time!