# How deep Is it possible to control colour font in subsections?

Tags: titlesec, sectsty

I am using this suggestion [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection) to use more level of sections and I would like to control the font colour as well.

I tried this so far

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputnc}

\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{sectsty}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother


\sectionfont{\color{blue}}
\subsectionfont{\color{orange!90!black}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{orange!70!white}}
\subsubsubsectionfont{\color{orange!50!white}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}



\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\tableofcontents


\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Introduction}
\subsubsection{Introduction}
\subsubsubsection{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: there are already two levels of section below subsubsection do you really need another, so 6 levels in all  `1.1.1.1.1.1 section` ? There is no answer to th quesion in the title, a class can define as many levels as it wans but few auhors ever need more than the 5 levels offered by `article` or 6 levels offered by `report` class.

Comment: Actually I would like to know how to control the colour fonts.

Comment: The definition of (say) `\paragraph` in `article.cls` is, in total `\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}`  just add `\color{red}` alongside `\bfseries` and it will be red, there is nothing special needed

Comment: Thank you, it worked. May you explain why this \subsubsubsectionfont{\color{orange!50!white}} does not work, please?

Comment: there is no `\subsubsubsection` command by default (the level after `\subsubsection` is called `\paragraph` so naturally unless you define it, there is no `\subsubsubsectionfont` command either.

Comment: Fair enough! Thx!!!