# is it possible to add more subsections like 1.2.3.4.5.6.7 in LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, subsection

Is it possible to add extra subsections?
example) \subsubsubsubsubsection

Comment: Do you really need more than 7 levels? We already have `\part` `\chapter` `\section` `\subsection` `\subsubsection` `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`, after all.

Comment: Having too deeply nested sections is not a good practice and it is a sign of bad design. You should consider to flatten the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, but what is an alternative option?

Comment: I thought this was obvious: structure your content in a way that makes do with fewer levels. But if you must: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection

Comment: I tried this to get upto 5 levels, but i need  upto 6 levels.

Comment: latex has 7 levels by default

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX standard classes support 7 levels of sectioning: `\part`, `\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph`, and `\subparagraph`. To make use of them as numbered sections you will need to [set `secnumdepth` appropriately](https://latexref.xyz/Sectioning.html), and possibly use [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en) to customize their appearance.

If you really need to go beyond 7 levels, you may want to look at Section 3.9 of the `titlesec` user manual; the package offers fairly convenient commands for creating additional sectioning levels, including inserting new ones between existing ones (so you can add a `\subsubsubsection` and a `\subsubparagraph` if you want to get to 9 levels.)