# How do I to indent headings and all their contents?

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I am somewhat new to LaTeX and I wish to have each level of heading indented more than the previous and have this effect the contents of that heading. Is this possible? If it is possible how would I do it and could it work on the subsubsubsections code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60212/305575?

```
1. Heading
  1.1 Subheading
    Text
    1.1.1 Subsubheading
      Text
  1.2 Subheading
    Text
2.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! But allow me the question: Why do you hate your readers? `;-)`

Comment: @campa yes thank you. That does help.

Comment: @campa I don't hate my readers, in fact I want all to feel welcome. Some people who have difficulty reading find that indentation helps then track information hierarchy and thus make the document easier to read. I simply want to be able to accommodate them.