# heading issue in latex

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I used following command `\paragraph` to number the heading. Then the next test immediately start after the heading. that I do not want.

Situation(I do not want this):

> 1.1.1.1 Heading: bla bla bla

I want:

> 1.1.1. Heading:
>
> bla bla bla

Thanks for response

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5035 probably answers yours question.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of numbers you see depends on the hierarchy level of the structure (`\paragraph` in your case). Therefore removing the last (or first) number would not be "LaTeX style".

IMHO the better way is to use the next higher  structure (`\subsubsection`) any change its layout as mentioned in this answer:
[Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti)

Without any change the result of `\subsubsection` is quite close to what you want:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\paragraph{test}
bla bla bla

\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsubsection{test}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

[image]