# \paragraph command start below heading

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

When using the \paragraph command, how do get the text that follows to start below the heading (and not in the same line)?

Comment: Hi, welcome. See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5035/paragraph-style-how-to-force-line-break-paragraph-make-paragraph-a-he helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `memoir` class then:

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir}
% ...
\setafterparskip{1.5ex plus .2ex}
% ...
\begin{document}
% ...
```

This will give you the same vertical space as between a `\subsubsection` and the text. See the manual (`> texdoc memoir` section *Lower level headings*) for details.

Answer (score 1):

For a standard class, you can use use `titlesec`. Here is a possible code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[block]
{\normalsize\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\hspace*{1.38em}}

\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{*1.5}{*0.5}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[10]
 \paragraph{Introduction}
 \lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want the paragraph indent before the title, remove the `\hspace*{1.38em}` in `\titleformat...`

The  star in `\titlespacing*...`  suppresses indent of the line that follows. The `{*1.5}` and `{*0.5}` are vertical spacings added to the normal line skip before and after the paragraph title, measured in `ex`, with some stretchability and some shrinkability. It saves you having to type the `plus` and `minus` parts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a **KOMA-Script class** then set `afterskip` for `paragraph` section level to a positive value:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  afterskip=1.5ex plus .2ex
]{paragraph}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[10]
\paragraph{Introduction}
\lipsum[11]
\end{document}
```