# Space between \paragraph{} and text

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, vertical

how do I put the text on a new row under a paragraph? My code is the following:

```
\paragraph{Title}
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text.
```

Right now It ends up like:

**Title** Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text.

I want it to be like:

**Title**

Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! `paragraph{...}` is intended to be inline with text. Do you can't  use  `\subsubsubsection{...}` for example?

Comment: [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60209/134144) might be interesting. Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5035/134144

Comment: @Zarko: Where is `\subsubsubsection` defined?

Comment: @Zarko??? the level after subsybsection is paragraph in all the standard classes.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, ups, one `sub` was to much ...

Answer (score 0):

`titlesec` package can help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Title}

\noindent
Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text, Some text.

\end{document}
```