# filling a vertical space in beginning of paragraph

Tags: spacing, setspace, vspace

I tried the following

```
\linespread{1.3}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Title Detection Computing}

\vspace{5mm}
Cloud smart alert correlation in Azure Security Center (incidents)
In the “publish or perish” age of academic research, many senior researchers advise their students and junior researchers about how to create professional document layouts, which software system to use, and which system is more efficient or user-friendly. Many of these senior researchers will attempt to convince their students and junior researchers that one system is “better”, “more elegant” “simpler”, or “more flexible” than the other system. There are very few researchers, however, who can confirm empirically how one system is superior to the other and on what basis they have drawn this conclusion. To date, no empirical studies exist to identify which system is more efficient. The preference toward a particular document preparation system can be particularly obstructive to the progress of research if the research question requires interdisciplinary teams. For example, a brain computer interface project may require collaborations between medical scientist
\vfill
\end{document}
```

The result generated was a paragraph with heading and some text like this one

[image]

I wanted to produce an effect same as we get when we press enter key on Microsoft word at the end of line or title and we get to new line.
I tried putting `\\` or `\newline`
but I got a message

```
There's no line here to end. \newline
```

I tried following also

```
\linespread{1.3}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Title title title}
\hfill \break
\vspace{5mm}
which system is more efficient. The preference toward a particular document preparation system can be particularly obstructive to the progress of research if the research question requires interdisciplinary teams. For example, a brain computer interface project may require collaborations between medical scientists, psychologists, computer scientists, biologists, physicists, and engineers. Any researcher who has ever collaborated on such large interdisciplinary projects has experienced the difficulty with \vfill
\end{document}
```

but the result I got was a not as I expected a gap of 5 mm between the start of title and the first line.
I have been reading tutorials from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Line_breaks_and_blank_spaces)
how ever I could not produce the desired result.
What am I missing?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5040/134144 might be interesting.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two options:

1) Use the `memoir` class (a superset of the `book`, `report` and `article` classes)  like

```
\documentclass[...]{memoir}
\setafterparskip{5mm}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{title}
\end{document}
```

2) Change the basic `\paragraph` definition, as shown in the MWE below (with the simpler `memoir` code commented out).

```
% paraprob.tex SE 535683 Don't run-in paragraph heading

\linespread{1.3}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
    {\z@}%
    {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
    {5mm}%
    {\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\makeatother

%\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
%\setafterparaskip{5mm}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Title Detection Computing}

\vspace{5mm}
Cloud smart alert correlation in Azure Security Center (incidents)
In the “publish or perish” age of academic research, many senior researchers advise their students and junior researchers about how to create professional document layouts, which software system to use, and which system is more efficient or user-friendly. Many of these senior researchers will attempt to convince their students and junior researchers that one system is “better”, “more elegant” “simpler”, or “more flexible” than the other system. There are very few researchers, however, who can confirm empirically how one system is superior to the other and on what basis they have drawn this conclusion. To date, no empirical studies exist to identify which system is more efficient. The preference toward a particular document preparation system can be particularly obstructive to the progress of research if the research question requires interdisciplinary teams. For example, a brain computer interface project may require collaborations between medical scientist
\vfill
\end{document}
```