# Adjust Space between \paragraph{} and the text after it

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I am writing my thesis and because I have many sections, subsections and subsubsections I had to use `\paragraph` to title some parts, the problem I am facing is the `\paragraph{title}` and the text after it are in the same line and I want the text to be in a new line. I tried `\\` and `\newline` nothing work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [paragraph style - how to force line break? \paragraph{} \\ - make paragraph a header?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5035/paragraph-style-how-to-force-line-break-paragraph-make-paragraph-a-he)